# Finding indices of subsequences of same values in a list ordered by length

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, group-by

There is this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214086/python-a-program-to-find-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-a-given-list), but not quite what I am asking.

Let's say I have a list of ones and zeroes:

```
# i.e. [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
sample = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10,)).tolist()
```

I am trying to find the index of subsequences of the same value, sorted by their length. So here, we would have the following sublists:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0]
[1]
[0]
[1]
```

So their indices would be `[4, 1, 0, 8, 9]`.

I can get the sorted subsequences doing this:

```
sorted([list(l) for n, l in itertools.groupby(sample)], key=lambda l: -len(l))
```

However, if I get repeated subsequences I won't be able to find the indices right away (I would have to use another loop).

I feel like there is a more straightforward and Pythonic way of doing what I'm after, just like the answer to the previous questions suggests. This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you show what the output is supposed to look like?

Comment: I did just that: `[4, 1, 0, 8, 9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create tuples of indices and values with `enumerate(..)`. Next you `groupby` but on the second element of the tuple, and finally you map them back on the second index. Like:

```
map(lambda x:x[0][0], # obtain the index of the first element
    sorted([list(l) for _,l in itertools.groupby(enumerate(sample), # create tuples with their indices
                                                 key=lambda x:x[1])], # group in value, not on index
           key=lambda l: -len(l)))
```

When running (the compressed command) in the console, it produces:

```
>>> map(lambda x:x[0][0],sorted([list(l) for _,l in itertools.groupby(enumerate(sample),key=lambda x:x[1])],key=lambda l: -len(l)))
[4, 1, 0, 8, 9]
```

> **N.B. 1**: instead of using `lambda l: -len(l)` as `key` when you sort, you can use `reverse=True` (and `key = len`), which is more
>   declarative, like:
>
> ```
> map(lambda x:x[0][0],
>     sorted([list(l) for _,l in itertools.groupby(enumerate(sample),
>                                                  key=lambda x:x[1])],
>            key=len, reverse=True))
> ```
>
> **N.B. 2**: In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) `map` will produce an **iterator** and not a list. You can *materialize* the result by calling `list(..)` on
>   the result.

Comment: Although this question is tagged Python 2, it's probably worth mentioning that `map` returns an iterator in Python 3, not a list, so you need to wrap that in a `list()` call. Or just use a list comp instead of `map`, that also has a benefit of using indexing directly instead of calling a function to do the indexing for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `groupby` the `sorted` function with generator function to do this efficiently.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

def gen(items):
    for _, elements in groupby(enumerate(items)):
        indexes, values = zip(*elements)
        yield indexes[0], values        

result = sorted(list(gen(data)), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Printing result yields:

```
[(4, (1, 1, 1, 1)), (1, (0, 0, 0)), (0, (1,)), (8, (0,)), (9, (1,))]
```