# Get the minimum successive value count, if any

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list, e.g.

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False]
```

and I want to know the minimal count that *True* is successive, hence 1 in this case.

Or in in the following list it is 2,

```
[True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please share what you have tried

Comment: You can get the minimum of the value given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342047/count-consecutive-occurences-of-values-varying-in-length-in-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my (naive) solution:

```
list_1 = [True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False]
list_2 = [True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True] 
list_3 = [False, False, False]
list_4 = [True, True, True]
list_5 = [False, False, False, True, True]

def min_successive_val_count(list_of_vals):
  list_of_runs = []
  counter = 0
  for val in list_of_vals:
    if val:
      counter+=1
    else:
      if counter != 0:
        list_of_runs.append(counter)
      counter = 0
  if list_of_runs:
    return min(list_of_runs)
  elif counter == len(list_of_vals):
    return counter
  elif list_of_vals[-1]:
    return counter
  else:
    return "No True's in your list"

print(min_successive_val_count(list_1))
print(min_successive_val_count(list_2))
print(min_successive_val_count(list_3))
print(min_successive_val_count(list_4))
print(min_successive_val_count(list_5))
```

Output:

```
1
2
No True's in your list
3
2
```

good luck (hopefully my last edit ;)

Comment: For a list completely consisting of `False` this should crash, as you are trying to calculate the minimum of an empty list

Comment: good catch, give me a min to edit

Comment: This also fails for a list completely consisting of `True`.

Comment: I like you - fixing now :)

Comment: If you are at it: consider testing the case `[False, False, False, True, True]` :D

Comment: Btw: I noticed those things because the solution I'm coding right now also failed all of them in the first try...

Comment: you are a better man than me - i went for the low hanging fruit and didn't even consider the edge cases

Comment: Many thanks, your awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

From [Python: A program to find the LENGTH of the longest run in a given list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214086/python-a-program-to-find-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-a-given-list) but with max -> min.

```
import itertools
lst = [True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False]
x = min(sum(1 for _ in l) for n, l in itertools.groupby(lst))

>>> x
    1
```

Comment: Nope, this does not care whether the shortest sequence consists of `False` or `True`. For example `[True, True, True, False]` will yield `x=1`

Answer (score 0):

lets use a dictionary to record our true counter while we traverse through this list.

```
list = [True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True]

currentCounter = 0

record = []

def getMin (list):   
    for x in list:
        if x:
            currentCounter[0] = currentCounter[0]+1
        else:
            record.append(currentCounter)
            currentCounter = 0
    return secondSmallest(record)

#we need to get the second smallet number because always the smallest is equal 0
def secondSmallest(numbers):
    m1, m2 = float('inf'), float('inf')
    for x in numbers:
        if x <= m1:
            m1, m2 = x, m1
        elif x < m2:
            m2 = x
    return m2
```